# Using xmlnamesspaces clause in XMLTABLE (Oracle)

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltable

I have been trying to get XMLTABLE to work and have been looking at similar posts but am still having problems. The query works but I dont get a value back and I cant see why.

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>185079144aba70c2b</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2014-03-10T11:01:18.893Z</CreDtTm>
      <InitgPty>
        <Id>
          <OrgId>
            <BICOrBEI>BARCGB22</BICOrBEI>
          </OrgId>
        </Id>
      </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
    <OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
      <OrgnlMsgId>AG00411310_1</OrgnlMsgId> 
      <OrgnlMsgNmId>pain.001.001.03</OrgnlMsgNmId>
      <OrgnlNbOfTxs>1</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
      <OrgnlCtrlSum>1234.56</OrgnlCtrlSum>
      <GrpSts>ACCP</GrpSts>
    </OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
    <OrgnlPmtInfAndSts>
      <OrgnlPmtInfId>AG00411310</OrgnlPmtInfId>
      <OrgnlNbOfTxs>1</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
      <OrgnlCtrlSum>1234.56</OrgnlCtrlSum>
      <PmtInfSts>ACCP</PmtInfSts>
      <TxInfAndSts>
        <OrgnlEndToEndId>AG700060000007</OrgnlEndToEndId>
        <TxSts>ACCP</TxSts>
        <OrgnlTxRef>
          <Amt>
            <InstdAmt Ccy="GBP">1234.56</InstdAmt>
          </Amt>
          <ReqdExctnDt>2014-03-06</ReqdExctnDt>
        </OrgnlTxRef>
      </TxInfAndSts>
    </OrgnlPmtInfAndSts>
  </CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</Document>
```

I have loaded the XML into an XMLTYPE column in a table I am using for basic testing called doctest (xml is in the column payload).  My sql query is below:

```
select ackd.BICorBIE
from doctest,
XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces ('urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03' as "b"),
'/b:Document' 
PASSING payload
COLUMNS
BICorBIE varchar2(20) PATH 'b:CstmrPmtStsRpt/GrpHdr/InitgPty/Id/OrgId/BICOrBEI') ackd;
```

The query executes without error but the column is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML declares a namespace but none of the nodes explicitly use it, so your XPath doesn't need to either. So, you can declare it in your statement as the *default* namespace, not with an identifier:

```
select ackd.bicorbie
from doctest
cross join xmltable (
  xmlnamespaces (default 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03'),
  '/Document' 
  passing payload
  columns
    bicorbie varchar2(20) path 'CstmrPmtStsRpt/GrpHdr/InitgPty/Id/OrgId/BICOrBEI'
) ackd;

BICORBIE            
--------------------
BARCGB22
```

You *can* still declare it as `"b"` if you want, but then you have to include it as a prefix for every node:

```
select ackd.bicorbie
from doctest
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces ('urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03' as "b"),
  '/b:Document' 
  passing payload
  columns
    bicorbie varchar2(20) path 'b:CstmrPmtStsRpt/b:GrpHdr/b:InitgPty/b:Id/b:OrgId/b:BICOrBEI'
) ackd;

BICORBIE            
--------------------
BARCGB22
```

Using a default here is simpler.